# How can i translate dynamic seo_url in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have dynamic laravel route. But i cannot translate this route when i use getTranslatedAttribute in the blade. I guess i got error because of the dynamic route.

i got this error.

Call to a member function getTranslatedAttribute() on null (View:/home/*/public_html/resources/views/*/*/*)

[image]

my route

```
Route::get('/en/solutions/{seo_url}', function ($seo_url) {
    App::setLocale('en');   

    $themes = App\Theme::all();     
    $services = App\Service::all();
    $referances = App\Referance::all();
    $blogs = App\Blog::all();
    $solutions = App\Solution::all();
    $announcements = App\Announcement::all();
    $news = App\News::all();
    $subsolutions = App\Subsolution::all(); 
    $solution_details = App\Solution::where('seo_url', $seo_url)->first();
    $pages = TCG\Voyager\Models\Page::all();         
    return view('tema.parallax.en.solution_detail', compact('services','solution_details','themes','pages'  , 'referances' , 'blogs' , 'solutions', 'subsolutions' , 'news', 'announcements') );
});
```

my blade

```
  <div class="container ms-content">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="row blog-sidebar grid-content col-lg-12">
                <div class="grid-sizer col-12"></div>
                @if ("en/solutions/" . $solution_details->getTranslatedAttribute('seo_url', 'en', 'fallbackLocale') == Request::path())

                <article class="grid-item col-12 pb-lg-5">
                    <div class="work-card card--is-link"> <figure
                            class="card__img media-wrapper media-wrapper--21:9"><img
                                src="/public/storage/{{$solution_details->resim}}"
                                alt="{!!$solution_details->getTranslatedAttribute('baslik', 'en', 'fallbackLocale')!!}">
                            <div class="glow-wrap"><i class="glow"></i></div>
                            </figure>
                         <br>   

                        <div class="card__content"><a class="card__title">
                                <h4>{!!$solution_details->getTranslatedAttribute('baslik', 'en', 'fallbackLocale')!!}
                                </h4>
                            </a>
                        
                            <p class="text-sm post-excerpt">{!!$solution_details->getTranslatedAttribute('aciklama',
                                'en', 'fallbackLocale')!!}</p>
                            <div class="post-info__footer"><span class="post-info__divider"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                @endif



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;


class Solution extends Model
{
    use Translatable;
    protected $translatable = ['baslik', 'aciklama', 'aciklama_kisa', 'seo_url' , 'seo_baslik' ,'seo_aciklama'];
}
```

In short, I want to translate my dynamic url.
How can i do that ?

Comment: Hi  Please post the error as text so search engines can find it. I'm pretty sure you found StackOverflow by searching an error message and getting possible resolutions to the problem. It's only fair you help others the same way by posting the error text (real filenames or not, your choice)

Comment: `first` can return `null` so it seems there was no database result for your query: `$solution_details = App\Solution::where('seo_url', $seo_url)->first();`

Comment: @lagbox there are results for my query but it doesn't when i try to translate the seo_url